# Can I autocomplete a command and its options in Windows XP and up?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, command-line

Having used linux I am used to the feature to autocomplete a command e.g. `iwlist` followed by its options, flags and switches e.g. `wlan0 scanning...`.

I attempted to do the same on Windows i.e. `netsh wlan show profiles` however am unable to autocomplete the options after `netsh ...`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and depending on which command line you are in, it performs slightly differently (Neither is as good as Linux).

cmd.exe (The traditional DOS looking one) will auto complete what is in the current working directory. If you `CD %systemroot%\windows32` and then try a command, it will autocomplete net to netsh for example. Other wise, it will autocomplete to documents, folders, or any file in the current directory.

PowerShell is slight better, it will auto complete cmdlets, and things like ipconfig, netsh as well as items in the currentl directory.

It will not auto complete out of order for these, for example:

I Can "ipcon<kbd>Tab</kbd>" to Ipconfig.
I cannot Get-AC<kbd>Tab</kbd> ipconf to get the string of commands "Get-ACL ipconfig".

PowerShell cmdlets only is better yet. Where I can do things like:

Get-Pro<kbd>Tab</kbd> -Na<kbd>Tab</kbd> fi<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> -<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and get: `Get-Process -Name firefox -FileVersionInfo`

So yes, it works to different degrees and effectiveness.